# What matters when optimizing a nginx server for audio/video streaming?

Tags: nginx, load-testing, video-streaming, jmeter

I am looking for opinions and resources. Serving rtmp, dash, hal with [nginx-rtmp-module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module). Test streaming from another machine with ffmpeg, but will probably use OBS later on.

1. Which nginx settings matter?
2. What's important in relation to hardware (cpu? ram? gpu?)?
3. How would you decide where the bottlenecks are, what causes performance issues?

I've been using JMeter with the [HLSPlugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/HLSPlugin) to do a bit of load testing. Increasing the number of threads has almost no impact on cpu/ram, but the stream did start to lag incrementally. JMeter is registering a bunch of 404 not found errors, when fetching media segments/playlists.

I'm looking forward to your comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: Thanks. Looks good, but I am trying to find out about the specificities of video streaming rather than load testing in general. In my own tests I have so far failed to establish a clear connection between the load, the errors and the hardware impact.